# cakePHP - Associated Model validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, cakephp

I have a `validate_form()` function which is called through ajax, which should validate input fields of an associated model from an action belonging to the main model..

This is the validation method

```
public function validate_form(){
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
            $this->request->data['Schedule'][$this->request->data['field']] = $this->request->data['value'];
            $this->Schedule->ScheduleContact->set($this->request->data);
            if($this->Schedule->ScheduleContact->validates()){
                $this->autoRender = false;
            }else{
                $error = $this->validateErrors($this->Schedule->ScheduleContact); //this pulls off all validation 
                //$this->set('debug_param', $error);
                $this->layout= 'ajax';
                echo $error[$this->request->data['field']][0]; //for the ScheduleContact Model, and puts it in an array
                $this->autoRender = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The ajax request is made whenever a blur event is fired :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#name, #surname, #email, #tel_no, #address, #city').blur(function(e){
        var self = e.target.id;
        $.post(
            '/name_project/schedules/validate_form', // it will submit to the validate_form action
            {field: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).val()},function(data){ 
            handleValidation(data,self) // data is the error.
            }
        );

    });
```

});

The request is made and there are no errors.. However the validation does not take place, and the validates() condition returns true every time whatsoever.. Any ideas why  ? Thanks

**[EDIT]**

This is a var_dump of the request data

```
array (size=3)
  'field' => string 'name' (length=4)
  'value' => string '' (length=0)
  'Schedule' => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: @MattDiamant thanks for the edit. But could you help me with this one? Thanks a heaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, what an idiot ive been these past 20 minutes. The answer lies with the request data as suspected.

Changed this line

`$this->request->data['Schedule'][$this->request->data['field']] = $this->request->data['value'];`

to this one

```
'$this->request->data['ScheduleContact'][$this->request->data['field']] = $this->request->data['value'];'
```